# performance test the code for finding time taken to fill the disk space

Tags: python, performance

I have written this module that takes input of configuration of multiple lines with first item as available storage and remaining are the process at different rate using `sys.stdin` .

```
#! /usr/bin/python

""" this script calculates the time remaining for available storage to get filled up.
"""

import sys

def time_to_meltdown(proc_r, available_storage):
    """
    this functions caclulates the time it will take to full the available disk space
    by n number of proceses by the rate of 1 byte after every d(p_i) seconds.

    :param list proc_r: number of process with constant but different rate memmory consumption
    :param int available_storage: total amount of free storage available on the farm.

    :return: time in seconds taken by n process to fill up the storage
    :rtype: int
    """
    mem = 0 # Initial consumption
    timeTaken = 0
    while mem < available_storage:
        timeTaken += 1 # increament each second by 1
        mem = 0
        for v in proc_r:
            mem += timeTaken // v
    return timeTaken


def main():
    """ this function builds data from the input and pass it
        to function that calculate time it will take to for
        available storage to get filled.
    """
    input_data = sys.stdin.read()
    config_lines = input_data.split("\n")
    for line in config_lines:
        if line:
            data = [int(data) for data in line.split() if data]
            available_storage = data[0]
            pr_i = data[1:]
            print "{} processes will take {} seconds to fill storage".format(len(pr_i), time_to_meltdown(pr_i, available_storage))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Please review the code for optimal performance.

When I run this code:

```
        while mem < available_storage:
        timeTaken += 1 # increament each second by 1
        mem = 0
        for v in proc_r:
            mem += timeTaken // v
    return timeTaken
```

above lines take quite substantial amount of time for long list of processes.

Comment: As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51719100/3403834), use binary search.

Comment: Yes I writing binary search.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to speed up the body of the loop using the `sum` function & list comprehension:

```
mem = sum( timeTaken // v for v in proc_r )
```

But the real speed up won’t come until you realize you can compute a lower limit for `timeTaken`, and begin looping starting from that value, instead of from zero.

Comment: I will write binary search and post updated.